# Why is the calendar module not installed in python?

Tags: python, pip, calendar

**Why is the calendar module not installed in python?**
An error occurs while upgrading the pip module to install the calendar module using pip in python, and then a traceback error occurs while trying to install the calendar module again.

**`pip install claendar`**

> [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0
> [notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

**`python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`**

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] 액세스가 거부되었습니다:         'c:\python311\scripts\pip.exe' Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

,and retry:
**`pip install calendar`**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
> File "", line 88, in *run_code
> File "C:\Python311\Scripts\pip.exe_*main**.py", line 4, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

**첨부 사진**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7CxL.png)

Comment: Have you tried `import calendar` ? I don't think that you need to install it.

Answer (score 0):

[*`calendar`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) is part of Python's standard library. It is always available and importable, there is no need to *pip*-install it.